# Unable to continue inputting parameters while looping to create objects for an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

edit: I solved it. The problem was that I was trying to clear the previous value held in the scanner in the wrong spot (needed it outside the if statements). I also cleaned up the continueInput method with a switch variable. I'll post the correct version as an answer.

I'm trying to create objects with a loop and then store them in an arraylist that I'll later print to file. I can create the first object just fine, but on the second iteration through the loop I can't move past entering the cartoon name. I get the prompt for the name, but nothing happens no matter what I enter.

Here's my main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
enum CartoonType{FOX,CHICKEN,RABBIT,MOUSE,DOG,CAT,BIRD,FISH,DUCK,RAT,NULL};

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<CartoonStar> cartoonStars = new ArrayList<CartoonStar>();
    String cartoonName;
    CartoonType cartoonType;
    String cartoonTypeString;
    int popularityIndex;
    boolean moreInput;
    int counter = 0;
    do {
        cartoonName = cartoonName(stdin);
        cartoonType = cartoonType(stdin);
        cartoonTypeString = cartoonType.toString();
        popularityIndex = popularityNumber(stdin);
        cartoonStars.add(new CartoonStar(cartoonName, cartoonType, popularityIndex));
        cartoonStars.get(counter).setName(cartoonName);
        cartoonStars.get(counter).setType(cartoonType);
        cartoonStars.get(counter).setPopularityIndex(popularityIndex);
        moreInput = continueInput(stdin);
        if (moreInput) {
            counter++;
        }
    } while (moreInput);
}

public static String cartoonName(Scanner stdin) {
    String name;
    String name1;
    int a = 1;
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the cartoon character: ");
    name = stdin.nextLine();
    do {
        name1 = name;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i))) {
                System.out.println("Please ensure you've entered the correct name. Re-enter the name or enter 'continue' to proceed: ");
                name = stdin.nextLine();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("continue")) {
                    a = 0;
                    name = name1;
                } else {
                    a = 1;
                }
            } else {
                a = 0;
            }
        }
    } while (a == 1);
    return name;
} // end of cartoonName method

public static CartoonType cartoonType(Scanner stdin) {
    int cartoonType = 0;
    CartoonType cType = CartoonType.valueOf("NULL");
    int a;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number corresponding to the type of cartoon character below.\n"
                    + "1 = FOX,2 = CHICKEN,3 = RABBIT,4 = MOUSE,5 = DOG,\n6 = CAT,7 = BIRD,8 = FISH,9 = DUCK,10 = RAT\n"
                    + "Please enter the type of cartoon character: ");
            cartoonType = stdin.nextInt();
            while (cartoonType < 1 || cartoonType > 10) {
                System.out.print("Sorry, please enter a number from 1 to 10. The corresponding types are:/n"
                        + "1 = FOX,2 = CHICKEN,3 = RABBIT,4 = MOUSE,5 = DOG,\n6 = CAT,7 = BIRD,8 = FISH,9 = DUCK,10 = RAT\n");
                cartoonType = stdin.nextInt();
            } 
            a = 0;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.print("Sorry, please enter only integer values.");
            a = 1; 
            stdin.nextLine(); // drop last input
        }
    } while (a == 1);
    switch (cartoonType) {
        case 1:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("FOX");
            break;
        case 2:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("CHICKEN");
            break;
        case 3:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("RABBIT");
            break;
        case 4:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("MOUSE");
            break;
        case 5:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("DOG");
            break;
        case 6:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("CAT");
            break;
        case 7:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("BIRD");
            break;
        case 8:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("FISH");
            break;
        case 9:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("DUCK");
            break;
        case 10:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("RAT");
            break;
    }
    return cType;
} // end of cartoonType method


public static int popularityNumber(Scanner stdin) {
    int popNum = 0;
    int a;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("Please enter a cartoon popularity number from 1 to 10, with 10 being the highest: ");
            popNum = stdin.nextInt();
            while (popNum < 1 || popNum > 10) {
                System.out.print("Sorry, please enter a value from 1 to 10: ");
                popNum = stdin.nextInt();
            }
            a = 1;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            a = 0;
            System.out.print("Sorry, please enter only integer values.");
            stdin.next();
        }
    } while (a == 0);
    return popNum;
} // end of popularityNumber method

public static boolean continueInput(Scanner stdin) {
    boolean moreInput = false;
    int a = 1;
    System.out.print("More input? Enter 'yes' for more input, or 'no' to quit: ");
    String input = stdin.next();
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i))) {
                System.out.println("Please enter only 'yes' or 'no'.");
                stdin.next();
                a = 1;
            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                a = 0;
                moreInput = true;
            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                a = 0;
                moreInput = false;
            } else {
                a = 1;
                System.out.print("Please enter only 'yes' or 'no'.");
                stdin.next();
            }
        }
    } while (a == 1);
    return moreInput;
}
```

}

And here's my other class:

```
public class CartoonStar {

 private String name;   
 private CartoonType type;   //enum types
 private int popularityIndex;  //1 to 10 10 being the most popular

 public CartoonStar() {
 }//end no argument construtor

 public CartoonStar(String name,CartoonType type, int popularityIndex) {
   setName(name);
   setType(type);
   setPopularityIndex(popularityIndex);
 }//end full constructor

 //getters and setters
 public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name;
 }      
 public String getName() {
   return name;
 }
 public void setType(CartoonType type) {
   this.type = type;
 }
 public CartoonType getType() {
   return type;
 }
 public void setPopularityIndex(int popularityIndex){
   this.popularityIndex = popularityIndex;
 }
 public int getPopularityIndex(){
   return popularityIndex;
 }  
}//end of class CartoonStar
```

Here's a sample output for my code:

```
Please enter the name of the cartoon character: w

Please enter a number corresponding to the type of cartoon character below.

1 = FOX,2 = CHICKEN,3 = RABBIT,4 = MOUSE,5 = DOG,

6 = CAT,7 = BIRD,8 = FISH,9 = DUCK,10 = RAT

Please enter the type of cartoon character: 2

Please enter a cartoon popularity number from 1 to 10, with 10 being the highest: 2

More input? Enter 'yes' for more input, or 'no' to quit: yes

Please enter the name of the cartoon character: w

BUILD STOPPED (total time: 11 seconds)
```

I stopped the program at this point because it just doesn't let me move past this point. Is the issue with the loop in my main method? I've never made objects without explicitly naming them, so I'm confused as to how to create them and later be able to recall them from my arraylist.

Comment: probably getting error due to `moreInput = continueInput(stdin);`and subsequent checking `if (moreInput)`

Comment: @KNU If I delete the if statement and just increment counter, nothing changes. Also, I can get completely through the first iteration of the loop, I just can't move past entering the name for the second object.

Comment: @user3397166 hi, u tried my suggestion?

Comment: @VD' Yeah, I responded on your comment. Using .reset() didn't change anything, but putting a .nextLine() in the if statement in my main method did help. But I still get an infinite loop if I enter anything other than yes or no when prompted to continue. It looks like my continueInput method has an error in it. I'm looking through that right now.

Comment: @user3397166 chk i have updated my ans for infinite loop, make those changes and it will work

Answer (score 0):

for infinite loop,

you need to assing new value entered by user to input variable in `continueInput`

like `input = stdin.next();`

so change it as following

```
public static boolean continueInput(Scanner stdin) {
    boolean moreInput = false;
    int a = 1;
    System.out.print("More input? Enter 'yes' for more input, or 'no' to quit: ");
    String input = stdin.next();
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i))) {
                System.out.println("Please enter only 'yes' or 'no'.");
                input = stdin.next();
                a = 1;
            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                a = 0;
                moreInput = true;
            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                a = 0;
                moreInput = false;
            } else {
                a = 1;
                System.out.print("Please enter only 'yes' or 'no'.");
                input = stdin.next();
            }
        }
    } while (a == 1);
    return moreInput;
}
```

Comment: So I updated my loop, discarding previous values using a stdin.nextLine() because the .reset() wasn't changing anything.This let me get through a complete second iteration, but when I'm prompted if I wish to continue no matter what I enter I'm being constantly reprompted to enter only yes or no (my exception handling). I don't understand why I'd be getting any exceptions when I just enter "yes".

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem was that I wasn't clearing the previous input from the scanner in the right spot. I was able to fix it, and I've posted my corrected main class as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected main class (cartoonstar class is unchanged):

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<CartoonStar> cartoonStars = new ArrayList<CartoonStar>();
    String cartoonName;
    CartoonType cartoonType;
    String cartoonTypeString;
    int popularityIndex;
    boolean moreInput;
    int counter = 0;
    do {
        cartoonName = cartoonName(stdin);
        cartoonType = cartoonType(stdin);
        cartoonTypeString = cartoonType.toString();
        popularityIndex = popularityNumber(stdin);
        cartoonStars.add(new CartoonStar(cartoonName, cartoonType, popularityIndex));
        cartoonStars.get(counter).setName(cartoonName);
        cartoonStars.get(counter).setType(cartoonType);
        cartoonStars.get(counter).setPopularityIndex(popularityIndex);
        moreInput = continueInput(stdin);
        counter++;
    } while (moreInput == true);
} // end of main method

public static String cartoonName(Scanner stdin) {
    String name;
    String name1;
    int a = 1;
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the cartoon character: ");
    name = stdin.nextLine();
    do {
        name1 = name;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i))) {
                System.out.println("Please ensure you've entered the correct name. Re-enter the name or enter 'continue' to proceed: ");
                name = stdin.nextLine();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("continue")) {
                    a = 0;
                    name = name1;
                } else {
                    a = 1;
                }
            } else {
                a = 0;
            }
        }
    } while (a == 1);
    return name;
} // end of cartoonName method

public static CartoonType cartoonType(Scanner stdin) {
    int cartoonType = 0;
    CartoonType cType = CartoonType.valueOf("NULL");
    int a;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number corresponding to the type of cartoon character below.\n"
                    + "1 = FOX,2 = CHICKEN,3 = RABBIT,4 = MOUSE,5 = DOG,\n6 = CAT,7 = BIRD,8 = FISH,9 = DUCK,10 = RAT\n"
                    + "Please enter the type of cartoon character: ");
            cartoonType = stdin.nextInt();
            while (cartoonType < 1 || cartoonType > 10) {
                System.out.print("Sorry, please enter a number from 1 to 10. The corresponding types are:/n"
                        + "1 = FOX,2 = CHICKEN,3 = RABBIT,4 = MOUSE,5 = DOG,\n6 = CAT,7 = BIRD,8 = FISH,9 = DUCK,10 = RAT\n");
                cartoonType = stdin.nextInt();
            } 
            a = 0;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.print("Sorry, please enter only integer values.");
            a = 1; 
            stdin.nextLine(); // drop last input
        }
    } while (a == 1);
    switch (cartoonType) {
        case 1:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("FOX");
            break;
        case 2:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("CHICKEN");
            break;
        case 3:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("RABBIT");
            break;
        case 4:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("MOUSE");
            break;
        case 5:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("DOG");
            break;
        case 6:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("CAT");
            break;
        case 7:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("BIRD");
            break;
        case 8:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("FISH");
            break;
        case 9:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("DUCK");
            break;
        case 10:
            cType = CartoonType.valueOf("RAT");
            break;
    }
    return cType;
} // end of cartoonType method


public static int popularityNumber(Scanner stdin) {
    int popNum = 0;
    int a;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("Please enter a cartoon popularity number from 1 to 10, with 10 being the highest: ");
            popNum = stdin.nextInt();
            while (popNum < 1 || popNum > 10) {
                System.out.print("Sorry, please enter a value from 1 to 10: ");
                popNum = stdin.nextInt();
            }
            a = 1;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            a = 0;
            System.out.print("Sorry, please enter only integer values.");
            stdin.next();
        }
    } while (a == 0);
    return popNum;
} // end of popularityNumber method

public static boolean continueInput(Scanner stdin) {
    boolean moreInput = false;
    int a;
    System.out.print("More input? Enter 'yes' for more input, or 'no' to quit: ");
    String input;
    do {
        switch (input = stdin.next().toLowerCase()) {
            case "yes":
                a = 0;
                moreInput = true;
                break;
            case "no":
                a = 0;
                moreInput = false;
                break;
            default:
                a = 1;
                System.out.print("Please enter only 'yes' or 'no'.");
        }
        stdin.nextLine();
    } while (a == 1);
    return moreInput;
} // end of continueInput method
```

}